# Awk: printing undetermined number of columns

Tags: awk

I have a file that contains a number of fields separated by tab. I am trying to print all columns except the first one but want to print them all in only *one* column with AWK. The format of the file is

```
col 1   col 2   ... col n
```

There are at least 2 columns in one row.

**Sample**

```
2012029754      901749095
2012028240      901744459       258789
2012024782      901735922
2012026032      901738573       257784
2012027260      901742004
2003062290      901738925       257813  257822
2012026806      901741040
2012024252      901733947       257493
2012024365      901733700
2012030848      901751693       260720  260956  264843  264844
```

So I want to tell awk to print column 2 to column n for n greater than 2 without printing blank lines when there is no info in column n of that row, all in one column like the following.

```
901749095
901744459
258789
901735922
901738573
257784
901742004
901738925
257813
257822
901741040
901733947
257493
901733700
901751693
260720
260956
264843
264844
```

This is the first time I am using awk, so bear with me. I wrote this from command line which works:

```
awk '{i=2; 
while ($i ~ /[0-9]+/)
{ 
    printf "%s\n", $i
    i++
}
}' bth.data
```

It is more of a seeking approval than asking a question whether it is the right way of doing something like this in AWK or is there a better/shorter way of doing it.

Note that the actual input file could be millions of lines.

Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused what output you expect, can you give some sample output for the input you show? Are you trying to skip column 1 and print everything else?

Comment: So, `cut -f 2- bth.data` doesn't do what you want?

Comment: Thanks Neil, but I want all in one column.

Comment: aren't you missing the first number (901749095 column 2 in line 1) in your output?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this what you want as output?

```
awk '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' bth.data
```

gives

```
901749095
901744459
258789
901735922
901738573
257784
901742004
901738925
257813
257822
901741040
901733947
257493
901733700
901751693
260720
260956
264843
264844
```

`NF` is one of several [pre-defined awk variables](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch07sec02.html). It indicates the number of fields on a given input line. For instance, it is useful if you want to always print out the last field in a line `print $NF`. Or of course if you want to iterate through all or part of the fields on a given line to the end of the line.

Comment: Yes. So NF is number of fields in a particular row, I assume?

Comment: @Hameed yes that is correct, I was just about to add some explanation to the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Seems like `awk` is the wrong tool.  I would do:

```
cut -f 2- < bth.data | tr -s '\t' '\n'
```

Note that with `-s`, this avoids printing blank lines as stated in the original problem.

Comment: Thanks. This works as well, however my original question was about AWK, so I don't want to un-accept the above answer. :)